# How to show 2 row in Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel for showing latest product working fine but now requirement are change client demand 2 row in carousel.i'm stuck here. here is backend code.

```
  <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">

               @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
                }
            </div>
```

[Html Result](http://www.screencast.com/t/nAKHfNx4mO9A)

how can i show 2 rows in single carousel.

Comment: Do not recognize syntax, your code is server-side probably.

Comment: yes this is server side code

Comment: Hopefully this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154151/owl-carousel-two-rows-issue